# Would the grease spell with a flask of acid used as a power component work with burning spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, metamagic

This [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87411/metamagic-burning-spell-and-acid-arrow) made me wonder whether this works.

A flask of acid can be used as a power component to add 1 point/ of acid damage per round to the effect of grease.

> Grease (M): The grease is acidic and deals 1 point of acid damage per
>   round to any creature in the area or holding the greased object.

Could I cast a burning grease with a flask of acid as a power component on an opponent's armor so that s/he is dealt 1 point of acid damage on round 1, 3 points of acid damage for the rest of the duration and 2 points on the round after the spell ends to the opponent?

When cast on CL 5 (when you get level 3 slots) that would be 5 minutes duration, which is 50 rounds.

Most armors should survive that because of hardness but unless it is removed that would mean 150 points of damage.

Edit: I missed that the feat mentions needing the acid or fire descriptor when I checked it.
Sorry That should not have happened.

Comment: Keep in mind that energy does half damage against objects, before applying hardness. Unless said object is vulnerable to that energy damage (gm fiat).

Comment: @ShadowKras That even helps the idea because I do not want to destroy the armor, just harm the one wearing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, unless you can add a fire/acid descriptor to the spell

[Burning Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/burning-spell-metamagic) clearly says that the spell must have the acid or fire descriptor, however, there are ways to change a spell descriptor to include acid/fire.

Such as the [Admixture Wizard's Arcane School](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/evocation/admixture):

> **Versatile Evocation (Su)**: When you cast an evocation spell that does acid, cold, electricity, or fire damage, you may change the damage dealt to one of the other four energy types. **This changes the descriptor of the spell to match the new energy type**. Any non-damaging effects remain unchanged unless the new energy type invalidates them (an ice storm that deals fire damage might still provide a penalty on Perception checks due to smoke, but it would not create difficult terrain). Such effects are subject to GM discretion. You can use this ability a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Intelligence modifier.

The Sorcerer Bloodlines that deal with elemental damage, such as [Elemental](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/elemental-bloodline), [Efreeti](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/efreeti-bloodline) and [Shaitan](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/shaitan-bloodline) bloodlines, all got an ability that adds fire or acid damage to the spell descriptor, such as:

> **Bloodline Arcana**: Whenever you cast a spell that deals energy damage, you can change the type of damage to fire. **This also changes the spell’s descriptors to match this energy type**.

The [Elemental Matamagic Rod](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/metamagic-rods/metamagic-elemental) however does not change the spell's type, as it works like [Elemental Spell feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/elemental-spell-metamagic), which doesn't include that specific ruling.

The [Bloatmage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/bloatmage) can also have the same powers as those sorcerer bloodlines mentioned before, using their 10th level ability **Absorb Bloodline**.

And finally, this is really stretching it, but seems to be legal from a *rules a written* standpoint:

All [Summon Monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) spells seems to be valid targets for [Burning Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/burning-spell-metamagic).

> When you use a summoning spell to summon a creature with an alignment or **elemental subtype**, it is a spell of that type.

Answer (score 3):

[Burning Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/burning-spell-metamagic) says:

> You cause creatures to take extra damage when you affect them with **a spell that has the acid or fire descriptor.**
>
> Benefit: The acid or fire effects of the affected spell adhere to the creature, causing more damage the next round. When a creature takes acid or fire damage from the affected spell, that creature takes damage equal to 2x the spell’s actual level at the start of its next turn. **The damage is acid or fire, as determined by the spell’s descriptor.** If a burning spell has both the fire and acid descriptor, the caster chooses what kind of damage is dealt by the burning spell effect.

By the letter of the rules, since [Grease](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/grease) doesn't have the acid descriptor, and since it doesn't say that using [Acid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/herbs-oils-other-substances#TOC-Acid) as a Power Component adds the descriptor, then the spell doesn't qualify for the effects of Burning Spell.

Your GM may rule that, because it adds an acid *effect* it should act as if it has the acid *descriptor*, but that would be a houserule.

Comment: I checked the feat but somehow missed the part about the descriptor. I might have thought the first sentence was just fluff.

Comment: There are way too few acid spells, to be honest.